# Cannot connect to EC2 ubuntu 18.04 instance after upgrading to Python3.9

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, python-3.9

I am using **EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 VM**.

Due to **[CVE-2021-3177](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-3177)**, Python needs to be upgraded to the latest version of Python3.9 which would be 3.9.9 currently.

I did that using the deadsnakes option as per the steps mentioned below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install python3.9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

The above ensures that Python3.9.9 is now available. But now python3.6 & python3.9 is available. So next we will use the update-alternatives command to make python3.9 as the default version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
```

Now that alternatives are defined, we will switch to Option 2 as the default option i.e. Python3.9

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Once done, the following command would point to the latest version.

```
sudo python3 -V
```

However, if you use the `sudo apt update` command, you will see an error stating that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

To fix this we will have to add a link using the following command

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
sudo ln -s apt-pkg.cpython-{36m,39m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Also below is optional, I tried with and without the following commands

```
apt purge python3-apt
apt install python3-apt
sudo apt install python3.9-distutils python3.9-dev
```

Once done following command will now not result in any errors

```
sudo apt update
```

This means that the issue is fixed.

**But for some reason, I cannot connect with the machine afterwards or if I create an AMI using this I cannot connect to the launched instance using PUTTY or SCP.**

**The same issue persists with Ubuntu-20.x too.**

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It would help understanding if anyone else also faced a similar issue, whether solved or not.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading Python, there are issues with the following Python modules that cloud-init depends on, which in turn prevents EC2 from being able to correctly configure your newly booted EC2 instance using cloud-init, and which is why it is inaccessible:

- setuptools
- urllib3
- requests
- jinja2
- netifaces

You can debug this issue by going to your EC2 instance in the AWS Web Console and clicking:

```
Actions -> Monitor and troubleshoot -> Get system log
```

Sometimes it takes a while to update, so click the refresh button until your logs appear.  It is easier to read the logs if you download them.  This is what helped me solve the issues that I was having.

The following steps resolved the issue for me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

*For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, change the `36m` in the symbolic links to `38`.*

```
# Add deadsnakes ppa repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

# Install new python version
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.10

# Fix broken apt_inst after python upgrade
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_inst.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_inst.so

# Fix broken apt_pkg after python upgrade
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so

# Make installed python version an alternative with a priority of 2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2

# Make upgraded python version an alternative with a priority of 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1

# Reinstall python3-apt
sudo apt remove --purge python3-apt
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install python3-apt

# Install required packages
sudo apt install \
build-essential \
python3.10-distutils \
python3.10-venv \
libpython3.10-dev

# Install latest pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python3.10 get-pip.py

# Upgrade outdated python libraries that break cloud-init
sudo -i
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade urllib3
pip3 install --upgrade requests
pip3 install --upgrade jinja2
pip3 install --upgrade netifaces
pip3 install --upgrade --ignore-installed pyyaml
exit

# Upgrade cloud-init to latest version
sudo apt install --only-upgrade cloud-init
```

If you use Ansible, it is also affected by the upgrade.

Ansible can be fixed as follows:

Edit `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py` and change the following line:

```
from collections import Mapping, Sequence
```

to:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping, Sequence
```

It would be useful if the deadsnakes repository could provide an update for python3-apt (eg. python3.10-apt) to solve this issue.

*Reference:
https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux*